# how to select rows dynamically in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2014

```
create procedure sp_getTransactionHistory
@market varchar(50)
As
BEGIN
declare @count int
**set  @count=100**
select TOP (@count) *,CONCAT(currency,'_',basecurrency) as market,(case when tradetype=0 then 'sell' else 'buy' end) as type 
           from tbl_TradingDetail where CONCAT(currency,'_',basecurrency)=@market order by tickerid desc
END
```

Comment: Please provide sample data, desired results, and an explanation of what your question means.

Comment: http://example.com/api/v1/history?market=btc_usd&count=5 here  count=6 or 7 or 8...